# Get Parent Value and Combine To Child Value Using Loop

Tags: php, loops, iteration

i have data and want to modify the result using parent and child method. As an example below.

[image]

I try with following code but have no luck because the last iteration give wrong result as seen on screenshot below, Is there any idea how to solve it?? live code here https://paiza.io/projects/vS4BHo0mMrKiJZoPpMoNvQ

```
<?php
    $data = array("022.04.GA", "4660", "4660.CBD", "4660.CBD.002", "52", "A", "533111", "022.04.WA", "4631", "4631.EAF", "4631.EAF.001", "51", "B", "524111", "524113", "52", "C", "521211", "524113", "4631.EAH", "4631.EAH.001", "51", "B", "521211", "522131", "4634", "4634.EAG", "4634.EAG.001", "51", "C", "521219", "522191");
    
            echo "<table>";
                  echo "<tr>";
                  echo "<td>Code</td><td>Result</td>";
    
                  foreach($data as $item)
                  {
                      $length = strlen($item);
                      $data   = '';
                      if($length==9) {
                          $value = $item;
                      } elseif($length==4) {
                          $value .= $data.'.'.$item;
                      } elseif($length==8) {
                          $output = substr($item,-4);
                          $value .= $data.$output;
                      } elseif($length==12) {
                          $output = substr($item,-4);
                          $value .= $data.$output;
                      } elseif($length==3) {
                          $value .= $data.'.'.$item;
                      } elseif($length==1 or $length==2) {
                          $value .= $data.'.'.$item;
                      } else {
                          $value .= $data.'.'.$item;
                      }
                      echo "<tr>";
                      echo "<td>$item</td>";
                      echo "<td>$value</td>";
    
                      echo "</tr>";
    
                  }
                  echo "</tr>";
                  echo "</table>";
?>
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you expect another result? length will be 6 so he will run `$value .= $data.'.'.$item;`

Comment: https://paiza.io/projects/vS4BHo0mMrKiJZoPpMoNvQ i try with online editor and it's not work

Comment: I think you don't understand me, i said i think that result is correct because "521219" have length 6 so the script will run else statment ( `$value .= $data.'.'.$item;` )

Comment: it's correct but how to make the result as i expected

Comment: We need to know logic of that, for example why with 521211 you need to concatenate and with 522191 no?